# Apache use case

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I use Apache to serve several sites to the world on my home server on port 443 using an SSL certificate. Last night I installed a linux binary that serves a site only on a port defined via its config file. It is not possible for me to have Apache serve the site directly.

So this site is hosted on http://127.0.0.1:8081/ but I would like to hide it behind Apache over 443 so that I can access it via https://myserver.duckdns.org/webapp/

I have tried this so far in my site config file but it has not worked:

```
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
        allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /webapp/$1 [P]

<Location /webapp/>
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</Location>
```

Any idea how I can do this?

I thought I could do this using ProxyPass and RewriteRules but I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: How exactly have you tried to do this so far?

Comment: @user1686 - Updated question to include what I have tried. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules a) have the wrong target and 2) are redundant.

RewriteRule with `[P]` is meant to be used as an *alternative* to ProxyPass, not together with it. The rewrite destination of a [P] rule would be the remote webapp URL, not a local one. For example, you could use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/webapp/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1 [P]
```

**or** this:

```
ProxyPass /webapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

**or** this:

```
<Location /webapp/>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</Location>
```

*(Note: The Apache documentation recommends using ProxyPass whenever possible.)*

Your `<Proxy *>` block is also unnecessary, because it only applies to *forward* proxying, where the client specifies the proxy destination (which you have disabled).

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was not understanding things correctly. I need to do more research here for sure. So I tried your suggestion of just using ProxyPass but for some reason the site does not load as expected. I am going to see if I can post a picture somewhere of what happens so maybe you can help me figure out what could be wrong. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: See what network requests happen in the browser's DevTools. Chances are the webapp is asking the browser to load resources (JS, CSS, images) from `http://127.0.0.1:8081` still, which is obviously not right from the browser's perspective... This might be when `ProxyPassReverse` becomes necessary. And in some cases, setting `ProxyPreserveHost On` might be enough to fix the issue (it lets the webapp see that it's being visited through "Host: myserver.duckdns.org"), but not always.

Comment: Yup! I suspect you are right. I uploaded the images. So here is the site loading correctly under it's originally hosted URL - https://imgur.com/7lXjj2K. And here it is not loading correctly under the ProxyPass directive - https://imgur.com/mpxOmLc. One other thing I noticed is that when you put http://<ip-address-of-server>:8081/ into a browser, I notice that the browser is being redirected to http://<ip-address-of-server>:8081/web/dashboard automatically by the application. You can probably see that in the address bar on the pic where the site is loading correctly.

Comment: And just to add that the site config file only contains ProxyPass /webapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/

Comment: Also tried adding ProxyPassReverse and ProxyPreserveHost directives and no change in behavior. Site is still not loading as expecting. The site config file currently contains is -> ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /webapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/
ProxyPassReverse /webapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/

Comment: Ah so you're still getting an error page from your Apache proxy itself, not from the backend webapp. Is that just `/web` at the end of your URL, instead of `/webapp/web`?

Comment: So I type in https://myserver.duckdns.org/webapp/ and the browser automatically shifts to what you see in the second picture i.e. https://myserver.duckdns.org/web which leads me to think that the ProxyPass is working as it is supposed to but the site itself is coded to redirect to /web/dashboard when called via it's published/bound URI which is http://<ip/hostname of server>:8081/. That's why I am wondering whether a clever Rewrite rule is needed to literally translate the URL I want to the URL the site wants if you catch my meaning. Interestingly if I don't try and use a custom alias.

Comment: Such as /webapp/ and literally have the ProxyPass pass '/' through to the site so what I mean is this -> ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/ then it works fine but ideally I do not want the site alias to be at root but rather a alias of my choosing.

Comment: So when you visit `/webapp`, due to the proxying, the webapp thinks you visited `/` and tries to redirect you to `/web` like it normally would. I think the ProxyPassReverse was _supposed to_ transform this into a `/webapp/web` redirect... but if you didn't have that enabled, the browser probably received the incorrect redirect to `/web` and cached it. Does it still happen in another browser / private mode / after clearing browser cache?

Comment: I just tried clearing my broswer cache, I tried using Edge and Chrome in both Private modes and still the same result. I am going to post the Apache access logs somewhere and will share them with you shortly.

Comment: So I stopped Apache, renamed access.log to something else and started it up again and then tried to access in Private Mode of both Edge and Chrome. Here is the access.log file generated from Apache if it helps -> https://transfer.sh/p8eck/access.log

Comment: And just to be clear, the URL I entered into a Private tab of both Edge and Chrome was https://<local server host name>/webapp/

Comment: So the more I look at this the more I think that it is the application that is serving the site that is the issue. I think the developer(s) have hardcoded a redirect. I can see evidence of this when I look at their source code on Github. With that in mind, I think the simplest solution is to use an Apache redirect for now. I have configured my site config file using the 'Redirect' directive and it is working as expected. I am going to mark user1686 as the accepted answer.